# Avoid labels overlap in bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlap, facet-wrap

How to avoid my y-axis label overlap in this case(top 5 most frequent words for each year)? Because I may need to change the number of words(ie.top10, top20) later, is there any way that the range of y-axis for each graph could be automatically adjusted based on the number of words that I want to analyze?

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(y = reorder_within(word, n, year),
                 x = n)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_reordered() +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Word",
       y = "Count") +
  facet_wrap(~ year, scales = "free") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 3)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: plot output]

Comment: Simply increase the height of the saved image. Try +ggsave("filename.png",device = "png", width = 5, height = 10)

Comment: If you click on the zoom button in R-studio, it should be also fixed.